# Replace PHP multiple if conditions without using case

Tags: php

I need to check the presence of multiple `$_GET` values to make `SQL` query according to the incoming `GET` values.

```
if(isset($_GET['va'])){ }

if(isset($_GET['vb'])){ }

if(isset($_GET['vc'])){ }

if(isset($_GET['vc'])){ }

if(isset($_GET['vd'])){ }

if(isset($_GET['ve'])){ }
```

I read an article about the impact of using multiple `IF` conditions.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What article and what impacts?

Comment: If you have to check the parameters, and you have 6 of them, then what's wrong with the way you implemented this? And BTW, `switch` is irrelevant because `isset` return either `true` or `false`

Comment: without knowing what you need to do it looks like a better way would be to have a parameter like `$_GET['type']` that can be set to 'va', 'vb', .. But it really depends on your usecase.

Comment: that's a lot of $_GET params - $_POST is safer and more of the standard nowadays. Either way, they're all different params, so you can't (and shouldn't) try to bundle them together

Comment: *"I read an article about the impact of using multiple IF conditions."* -- the impact of multiple IF conditions is 1000 times smaller than the impact of a SQL query.

Comment: In the article they recommend not to use  IF conditions multiple times(in my case the number is high)

Comment: @MuhammedAsif can you link the article?

Comment: I think you misunderstand that article, or maybe there's something else I'm missing here, because there's no rule against it, specifically with the code you presented

Comment: @axiac thanks for the information

Comment: @Script47 https://gist.github.com/bsalim/4442047

Comment: ['*Do use switch over lots of if statements*'](https://gist.github.com/bsalim/4442047#file-php-speed-up-tips-html-L58)

Comment: @MuhammedAsif If you're talking about line 58, they meant that you should avoid `if( $a == 1) { .. } else if ($a == 2) { } else if( $a == 3) {} else {}`, and instead you should `switch( $a) { case 1: ..break; case 2: ..break; case 3: ..break; default: break;}`

Comment: That "article" is a complete disaster and you should forget everything it told you. "*Error messages are expensive*" - what?

Comment: could anybody helps me to improve the performance if i share the algorithm here?

Comment: @MuhammedAsif It doesn't look like you have any issue with the code, but you can always [edit] your post and include more details

Comment: @iainn Logging the error produced by `echo $_GET[va];` thousands of times per second could wreak havoc on a system so "*Error messages are expensive*" does have merit under the right circumstance. However, the "tips and tricks" speak in the sense of "always do this" and most of us know it's foolish to blindly follow garbage like that.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, exactly. In the right context, some of the tips there make (some) sense, but unless that context is provided they're completely pointless. That's ignoring the half of them that are just outright wrong.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that make more sense, Practically we can experience the lack of performance if the page has too many errors/warnings.

Comment: @MuhammedAsif There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code which you have posted and I would write the same exact code if I was in your position. Without knowing more context then I would say your code is perfectly performant.